# How to Enter a sequence of alphabet in 9x9 matrix and then the alphabet put values in that matrix to create an image in python, how do i do that?

Tags: python

I want to create a image from a sequence. The sequence is in upperletter alphabet so I want to put the sequence into 9x9 matrix but it will take only value not the alphabet it put alphabet value into the matrix.

Comment: Could you provide some code you might of already tried or perhaps a little more information so we would be better equiped to lending a hand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do what you are asking:

```
# Create string of 81 uppercase letters
string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'*3 + 'ABC'

# Assign each letter a number, and scale the numbers from 0 to 1
num = [(ord(string[char]) - 65)/25 for char in range(len(string))]

# Assemble the numbers into a 9x9 matrix
x = np.reshape(num,[9,9])

# Create an image with the color defined by the numbers
plt.imshow(x)

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations
idx = -1
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        idx += 1
        text = plt.gca().text(j, i, string[idx],
                       ha='center', va='center', color='w')
```

[image: Image from letters]

Comment: If I want to see the values in the matrix then and I have a dna sequence in a doc file so it should read the sequence from there and show images for every 81 character in 9x9 matrix and sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: @ArefinZamshed I have updated my answer to show how to annotate the text values in the matrix. Can show the numeric values instead by changing ``string`` to ``num`` in the loop.